# Stuck with Exception Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When i build the project it shows me the Exception that "app:mergeDebugResources"
i checked my whole code and build.gradle and also the manifest file; i couldn't understand what is the main problem:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources                  Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Here is my menifiest file:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".dashboard.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".dashboard.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.Alphabcha"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.Alphabets"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.Numbers"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.Tables"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".dashboard.Help"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".dashboard.AboutUs"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.Rhymes"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Ones"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Two"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Third"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Fourth"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Fifth"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Six"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Seven"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Eight"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Nine"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".childActivities.tableSubChilds.Ten"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.rhymesSubChilds.Bababl"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.rhymesSubChilds.Hotcross"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.rhymesSubChilds.Twink"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.rhymesSubChilds.Humptydu"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.rhymesSubChilds.Jackjill"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.rhymesSubChilds.Mary"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".childActivities.Shapes"></activity>
</application>
```

`

and here is my build.gradle file:   `

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'  // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
}
```

I'm not using any jar file in lib in this project.looking for some  helpful answer. Thanks in advance .

Comment: show full `build.gradle`

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "****"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

Comment: set 25 `compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion ` and app compat `v7:25.1.0`

Comment: still facing the same problem :-(

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: i already added

Comment: Could you post your total `build.gradle`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132166/discussion-between---and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: I just had this problem. It was caused by a drawable that I added into my folder; after I removed it, everything was back to normal. Note: this drawable was a 9 patch image.

Comment: @Ядм Жцмдшдт Can you help me how to solve this issue i am facing same problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: O got the problem because of images  so use all the formats of images (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi,xxhdpi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just faced the same problem. I deleted my drawable file and tried to get it one by one and checked. I checked XML file where I have used it, it showed me error:

> "Unable to load image".

So, there is problem in the image, I just replaced the old one with a new image and it works!

Answer (score 11):

I just faced the same problem.
I accidently deleted my drawable file and tried to get it by doing Ctrl+z.
I checked xml file where I have used it, it showed me error "Unable to load image".
So, this is problem in image, I just then deleted old and uploaded new. It worked !

Answer (score 6):

I just had this problem.

After some investigation, I found that was a 9 patch image that was added on the resources folder. The problem was that on this 9 patch I added transparency, by mistake, at the reference border (those black borders).

So, after I fixed the 9 patch, which means remove the transparency of, the problem was solved.

Comment: Yup, a 9 patch image was the culprit for me too.

Answer (score 3):

There will be 9 patch images added to the project, or filename issues in the drawable folder, try to change the compiled version and targeted version and rebuild the project.

Comment: can you please explain "9 patch images"
@Manoj Frekzz

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the exact same problem yesterday, it's the **problem with IDE** probably because Android Studio **forces Gradle Support** into the project .Importing the same project with the fresh sources to **Eclipse** worked for me. Here's the error log: https://s27.postimg.org/n6nlos2sz/Screenshot_64.png 
Hope this helps.

#### Import to eclipse guide

Eclipse Setup: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers/neonm6

Just extract the downloaded package, and use the option to **import** existing Android Project.If it says **Android SDK not configured**, go to configure option and add the SDK path(you can find that in the Android Studio SDK Manager option). Also do check which version of API it needs and install it from the SDK Manager.

If you get an error : **unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:XX'**,
install that version from SDK.

Don't forget to add **Google API package** in the packages list, as SDK Platform package is different from Google APIs package.

link-->[https]s24[dot]postimg[dot]org/jq3bgwv39/Screenshot_66.png

After this Delete the Workspace folder and again try to import the project.

Comment: Switching to a deprecated IDE is a pretty drastic solution.  Google isn't supporting Eclipse for Android development anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

To address the above type of errors, go to "res" directory and check the folders drawable, drawable-XXXX etc for possible .png images. Remove the ".9" from the .png images. Perform "Build/Clean Project" followed up by "Build/Rebuild Project".

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got this issue because my project was imported from Eclipse to Android Studio and dependencies were missing in gradle.

I got rid of it after adding

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

in

```
defaultConfig {
}
```

below

```
targetSdkVersion 25
```

After, this I had to set

```
minSdkVersion 9
```

Also, I added following lines

```
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
```

above

```
'defaultConfig' {
}
```

So, that it looks like,

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        }
        //remaining code snippet
        //.....
    }
    //remaining code snippet
    //.....
}
```

Hope, it will help someone, someday. Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably having this error because you imported the project and the gradle file of this project is slightly different from what usually works on your android studio.

1. Locate "build" in your android studio, on the dropdown of build, you will see clean project. click on it.
2. If you still have the errors, and/or when you open your `MainActivity.java` file, you see that R cannot be resolved. then you need to go to your build.gradle file.
3. Open an existing project that runs/compiles without errors on your android studio (open in another window). Now you have 2 projects open on android studio
4. Open the build.gradle (module app) file of the existing project and copy everything in this file (everything in the build.gradle file)
5. Go to the project with errors, clear out whatever is in the build.gradle file and paste that of the existing project that you have copied and put it here.
6. Build your project or click on sync now that pops up at the top right corner of this build.gradle and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

please check that in your drawable folder if there is any nine patch image so remove that then try it. It work for me same.