# Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Tags: android, gradle

This is the output of my gradle console please help me out to solve this error, I am unable to build my project

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:facebook:generateDebugSources, :facebook:mockableAndroidJar, :facebook:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :facebook:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :lagaiKhai:generateDebugSources, :lagaiKhai:mockableAndroidJar, :lagaiKhai:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :lagaiKhai:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:Execution failed for task ':lagaiKhai:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 23.24 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438679/stuck-with-exception-errorjava-util-concurrent-executionexception-com-android

Comment: Issue with drawable foalder, check all images extension are proper

Comment: I tried all this possible scenarios but still i am facing the same problem

Comment: @vishesh268 can u post ur whole error log. Its saying 2 errors lets see what are those

Comment: @Mrinmoy it worked, thank you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I once accidently added .gif file in drawable folder, and faced this issue, if you find any unwanted file in drawable folder.

Follow the following steps:-

- Remove all such files which are not recognised by drawable foalder (.gif, 9-patch, etc).
- Close android studio and start it again
- Clean and build project again

You are good to go again!

Comment: I have done this but the Error in now showing in the resource files of facebook library        this is the error i am getting ----discarded: Crunching single PNG file: C:\New folder\lagai_khai_android\lagaiKhai\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\lagai_khai_android\facebook\unspecified\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\com_facebook_tooltip_blue_bottomnub.png

Comment: try deleting com_facebo‌​ok_tooltip_blue_bott‌​omnub.png from the specified path

Comment: This fixed my same error. This is the only answer that mentioned 9-patch as a problem. I had made 3 changes and backed them out with no success. I followed several of the various 20+ answers for this error with no lick. Only after reading this did I remember I had made a 9-patch png using Android studio-> right click on png file and make 9-patch from it.  This answer was my saving grace. Thank you Mrinmoy +10 if I knew how to send it your way!

Answer (score 12):

A temporary solution is to place the code below in the module `build.gradle`:

```
android { 
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}
```

And Sync the Project.Works for me.`

Answer (score 5):

Try checking all the recentenly added 9patch files. they all must have the content markers on the 4 sides of the image

Comment: In my case I used third party tool to generate nine patches. So I open each file in android studio nine patch editor and changed every file a bit (moving patches borders). This was fixed issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I created a 9-Patch file according to https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html, as a result of that, I faced the same error.

I had drew just the parts I wanted to stretch, but not the entire line.

To fix it I drew the entire right and bottom lines of the 9-patch, and the parts I wanted to stretch I did it on the left and top lines.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Invalidate Cache and Restart Invalidate Cache and Restart option in android studio and it worked for me.

[image: Invalidate Cache and Restart]

Answer (score 0):

most of the time is a corrupt PNG image added recently to the project which cause this error. Check the git log and replace the file.

Sometimes menu : File > InvalidateCaches/Restart also helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the .9 patch image file which you have added in the drawable.

To fix the issue.

1) Check you have named the 9 patch image as(***file_name.png to file_name.9.png***). E.g: "myimage.9.png" in the drawable folder.

2) **Must Ensure** that the 9 patch image file contains the "Content Marker on the 4 sides of the image". (i.e: if you open the image in Android studio, you will able to view 4 black lines on 4 sides of the image.)

3) if you not able to view the Content Marker on the sides of the image, then kindly rename the image file from (***file_name.9.png to file_name.png***), the error will be vanished.