# Gradle Task Build Error Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, debugging, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
C:\Users\S.T.ANNAN\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstAndroidApp2\app\src\main\res\layout\content_main.xml
Error:(50) error: not well-formed (invalid token).
Error:(50) not well-formed (invalid token).
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 9s
>   Information:4 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: In this link may be you get solution of your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712985/error-java-util-concurrent-executionexception-com-android-ide-common-process-p/41713188

Comment: Please, put your gradle json here.

Comment: Hi jhonatan2760. Please where do i locate my gradle json?

Comment: It looks like there's invalid code in the content_main.xml file. Can you post the contents of it?

Comment: Hi. I just had to restructure my code and place the curly brackets appropriately. Thanks for your help.