# Run build failed in Android Studio 3.1.3 for Windows 10 Home 64bit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

```
[Attached Screenshot of my dashboard][1]

Here's all the activity on my 'activity_main.xml' file:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="16dp"
 android:paddingLeft="16dp"
 android:paddingRight="16dp"
 android:paddingTop="16dp"
 android:visibility="visible"
 tools:context=".MainActivity"
 tools:onClick="onButtonTap">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/fab"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
   android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
   android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
   app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

   <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/imageButton"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_above="@+id/null"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginBottom="-92dp"
   app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="174dp"
 android:text="Tap me if you dare!" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="234dp"
android:text="@string/tapme" />

</RelativeLayout>


Hopefully this should help. Thanks!
```

**Run build failed with the following error message:**
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process

C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \?\C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.screwedupminds.firstapp -0 apk --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:807)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar -M \?\C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \?\C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.screwedupminds.firstapp -0 apk --output-text-symbols \?\C:\Users\NITISHA KUNDU\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeqak.jpg
```

Comment: I think you have still skipped some important lines of the stack trace, haven't you?

Comment: why am i receiving these error msgs? My emulator is showing but it does not run the app.

Comment: Yeah I do have more errors under "Run tasks" and "Android Issues"

Comment: Why don't you post some relevant code and only an important part of the stacktrace?

Comment: Im a first timer. Is there some way I can mail you a screenshot for you to point me in the right direction with what exactly you require from me? Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might wanna check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712985/error-java-util-concurrent-executionexception-com-android-ide-common-process-p/43292424

Comment: Yes i have already seen that. There's nothing there that I have added extra on the drawable. Just has these 2 files under it: ic_launcher_background.xml and ic_launcher_foreground.xml(v24)

Comment: If possible can I mail you screenshots so that you can have a detailed look?

Comment: you can add screenshots on your post too

Comment: Done. Have a look and pls do let me know if you see something funny or want any specific screenshot. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Your image says "invalid symbol: 'null'" in activity_main.xml. Can you include the full activity_main.xml file (as text, not an image) in your question?

Comment: @TylerV - Done. Edited in the first half of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use `android:id="@+id/null"` instead of `android:layout_above="@+id/null"`

If not then you forgot to add `android:id="@+id/null"` to the view you want your `ImageView` to be below and also remove the `+` in `android:layout_above="@+id/null"`.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution this kind of problems is to delete the project and build the project once again. Hope your problem is solved.